# Hint for Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'm developing a theme for wordpress and would like to know the best way to show highlights on the home page.

Examples:
[image: highlights]

[image]

I thought two ways:

- Custom post types -a custom post "highlight" with metabox for image, text and link.
- Theme Options - a page with options for each box.

What is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Neither. What you want can be achieved using either Wordpress' core functions and/or Custom Fields. Consider using [Custom Meta Boxes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) if you have a client that requires a more intuitive setup, or installing something like the [Types Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/) to do it for you.

This will allow you to attach your own variables to given Posts/Pages.

To gain access to a post's Custom Fields, click the Screen Options button at the top of the Post Editor to enable Custom Fields.

Personally, I would [Enable Support for Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) for your Highlights image, use [The Excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) for your Highlight copy, and use either [The Title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) or a [Custom Field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) for the heading.

This way, you can keep all your eggs in one basket rather than overcomplicating things with Custom Post Types or Theme Options Pages.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you give a practical example? My initial idea was to make a loop to "highlight" CPT on the homepage. In your suggestion, How the user will choose the "highlight" he want?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Plugin "Ether Content Builder"

Answer (score 0):

You could use either of the methods you've suggested.  In my opinion getting involved with lots of meta boxes on one specific page template for this is a total waste of time - there is only an image, a header and an excerpt linking to a post/page. Three posts (whether custom or not) will handle that with featured image, excerpt and the page/post title.

I also think doing a Custom Post type is too much just for three posts on the homepage.  If you go the posts route just create a new post category called Home Highlights and put your three posts in there, pull them in via a custom loop built on WP_Query.

Yes you can go the Theme Options route too.  If it's the client updating the site then it can look quite professional this way, I've started using a plugin called [Options Tree](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/option-tree/) after it came integrated with Super Skeleton, it makes it very easy to build your custom theme options which work just as well too.

A matter of opinion really, rather than a hard and fast 'this one is definitely better'!

Comment: Thanks! I was reading about metabox with checkbox...It could be a nice way too:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28785/how-set-featured-posts-using-checkbox-in-post-edit-screen